# Mylyn connectors for GitHub and BitBucket

Tags: mercurial, github, bitbucket, mylyn

Does anyone know if there are any stable connectors to integrate mylyn with Bitbucket and Github?

For github.com I think I found one, but for bitbucket there is no information on the Eclipse Mylyn project page.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Mylyn connector for Bitbucket at [https://bitbucket.org/pplupo/bitbucket-mylyn-connector](https://bitbucket.org/pplupo/bitbucket-mylyn-connector/wiki/Home).

*Note: the Eclipse Update Site there (http://www.mylynbitbucketconnector.xpg.com.br/update) only worked for me when I unchecked "Group items by category"*

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 comes with EGit and Mylyn GitHub connector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the following post on the MercurialEclipse forum for a Mylyn connector for Bitbucket's issue feature:

http://groups.google.com/group/mercurialeclipse/browse_thread/thread/e4c5f113f127e0b1?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing the GitHub connector for MyLyn. 
http://devsprint.github.com/org.eclipse.mylyn.github/site

If you have any suggestions then please log them into github issues.
https://github.com/devsprint/org.eclipse.mylyn.github/issues