# Using github issues as mylyn task repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, mylyn

I'm looking for a way to integrate Eclipse/Mylyn with github's project-**issues**.

I'm aware of the [Mylyn-github-connector](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_Tasks) and the [smilebase project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680400/mylyn-connectors-for-github-and-mercurial), but - unless I'm totally wrong - both connectors only allow to associate existing tasks with github commits. There is no option to use github issues as a task repository.

I also found this slightly related [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680400/mylyn-connectors-for-github-and-mercurial), but besides the fact that the provided link is dead it seems to focus on the connector itself (not the task repository)

Thanks for answering,

Jan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the connector you want: [org.eclipse.mylyn.github](https://github.com/dgreen99/org.eclipse.mylyn.github/wiki/) (it is a fork of the one posted in the related question). I have been using it and it works great.

Comment: How do you get it to store mylyn contexts?  Seems useless without that  ability.

Comment: This project predates the new GitHub API.  Instead of using this one, prefer the new connector that is maintained as part of EGit (referenced on this page)

Answer (score 4):

The GitHub Mylyn Connector is now an official Eclipse project under EGit.

The 1.0 release was part of Indigo and is available from the EGit update site under the *Collaboration* category:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

1.1 nightlies are also available with support for pull requests:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates-nightly

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/blog/852-github-mylyn-connector-for-eclipse) for the announcement.